# running system calls inside MySql trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, system-calls

how can i execute system calls within a trigger?
my code currently looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER trig AFTER INSERT ON tbl1
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        system 'echo 123';
END$$
```

what is the right syntax?

i'm still pretty new to DB,
thanks in advance.

Comment: from where are you calling this script? php or shell, or something else?

Comment: You could write a C user-defined-function, I suppose. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html

Comment: @SavasVedova I'm currently trying to run it from the MySql Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't execute system calls from SQL trigger.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41094